# Operation on `nil` in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Expressions like this will cause an error

```
(= nil 3)


Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
=(nil .......
```

Then is there an easy way(for example, another function called `my-eq`) to make this expression returns `nil`(means False) like this:

```
(my-eq nil 3)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's `eq` or `equal`.

(eq 3 nil)

=> nil

```
(eq OBJ1 OBJ2)

Return t if the two args are the same Lisp object.

(equal O1 O2)

Return t if two Lisp objects have similar structure and contents.
They must have the same data type.
Conses are compared by comparing the cars and the cdrs.
Vectors and strings are compared element by element.
Numbers are compared by value, but integers cannot equal floats.
 (Use `=' if you want integers and floats to be able to be equal.)
Symbols must match exactly.
```

Comment: There is also the `null` predicate; `(null nil) => t`